# Splitting .txt file in c# according to the initial letter in each line

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to split .txt file with one sentence in each line to two .txt files,
in the first .txt file there should only be sentences with initial letter A,B,C,...,N.
In the second .txt file there should only be sentences with initial letter O,P,Q,...,Z.

There is what I tried :

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStreamReader sr = new MyStreamReader();
        sr.ReadMyFile();



        MyStreamWriter sw = new MyStreamWriter();
        sw.WriteMyFile();

        MyStreamWriter2 sw2 = new MyStreamWriter2();
        sw2.WriteMyFile2();
    }

    static void Declare()
    { public StringBuilder AtoN;
    public StringBuilder OtoZ; }
    
    
    class MyStreamWriter
    {
        public void WriteMyFile(StringBuilder AtoN)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            try
            {
                sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ProgramkoTest\FirstHalf");
                sw.WriteLine(AtoN);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sw != null)
                {
                    sw.Close();
                    sw.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
class MyStreamWriter2
{
    public void WriteMyFile2(StringBuilder OtoZ)
    {
        StreamWriter sw2 = null;
        try
        {
            sw2 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ProgramkoTest\SecondHalf");
            sw2.WriteLine(OtoZ);
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e2.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sw2 != null)
            {
                sw2.Close();
                sw2.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
class MyStreamReader
    {
        public void ReadMyFile(StringBuilder AtoN, StringBuilder OtoZ)
        {
            StreamReader sr = null;
            string line = null;
            try
            {
                string pathToTestFile = @"C:\ProgramkoTest\LinesToSplit.txt";

                sr = new StreamReader(pathToTestFile);
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        char linePart0 = line[0];
                        if (linePart0 > 64 && linePart0 < 79)
                        {
                            StringBuilder AtoN = new StringBuilder(line);
                        }
                        else if (linePart0 > 79 && linePart0 < 91)
                        {
                            StringBuilder OtoZ = new StringBuilder(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sr != null)
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    sr.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched that in the unicode capital A has a value 65. So I try what value first letter in each line has and then I put it in StringBuilder. Thanks for help.

Comment: You should be getting compile time errors because you call `sr.ReadMyFile();` without the required `StringBuilder` parameters...

Comment: How can I repair that ?

Comment: ... Call the functions with their required parameters? Consider taking some tutorials on C# and basics of programming with methods and parameters.

Comment: When I did that it just show more errors...

Comment: "show more errors" So, it was showing errors before? Please be as complete with your questions as you can and provide the text of any errors that are occurring. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Yes, it was. That's why I need help with it. And also I want to know what should I do to make it working.

Comment: Right, but in order for us to help with it, we need to know what the errors are. It's part of the "contract" here; you tell us what the problems are, we tell you how to fix them. It's a lot more efficient that way than for us to guess what the problems are (as the current  answer does), you tell us what's wrong, we edit, you tell us what's still wrong, etc., etc..

Comment: I though people will take my code they see and they will suggest how to repair the errors, when I write there 24 errors and 18 of them are because of something stupid (I feel like the bruckets were bugging for me because I originally got only about 8 mistakes)I will get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

the basic logic should look like this (if I have not misunderstood your requirement):

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace MyDemoApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder builderA = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder builderB = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"e:\MyInputFile.txt"))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    char firstChar = line.ToUpperInvariant()[0];

                    if (firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <= 'N')
                    {
                        builderA.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                    else if (firstChar >= 'O' && firstChar <= 'Z')
                    {
                        builderB.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // TODO: numbers, special characters ...
                    }
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"e:\\fileA.txt", builderA.ToString());
            File.WriteAllText(@"e:\\fileB.txt", builderB.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Of course, there is still room for optimisation. But essentially it does what you described.

Comment: Thanks, I want to ask where can I read something about the File. ... you were using.

Comment: Do I need something like : using System.File; ?

Comment: @David395, using System.IO (is where File is located)

Comment: Yeah thanks Im stupid that's the same I used for StreamRider and StreamWriter...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one, to save up some memory because only a single line is kept in memory. Might also be faster:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testfile.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter aToNWriter = new StreamWriter("outputA-N.txt"))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter oToZWriter = new StreamWriter("outputO-Z.txt"))
                    {
                        string line = null;
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                continue;

                            char firstCharInLine = line[0];

                            if (firstCharInLine >= 'A' && firstCharInLine <= 'N')
                            {
                                aToNWriter.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                oToZWriter.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```